# URL does not point to a valid file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project. I have help.component.html and help.component.scss file in the same folder as help.component.ts. But in my .ts file templateUrl and styleUrls are underlined in red saying "URL does not point to a valid file". My code is given below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './help.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
  providers: [DataService]
})
```

Comment: have you tried templateUrl: 'help.component.html' ?

Comment: @pbachman yes, I tried that.

Comment: Are you sure the names/extensions of those files are correct ? It indeed occurs when it cant find the file specified.

Comment: Restart your IDE, it might help

Comment: @Kirubel actually restarting the IDE worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Angular IDE. as @Kirubel mentioned in the comments Restarting the IDE worked for me.